# Select Entire Sheets for Printing: Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I created a VBA macro to export specific sheets of a workbook to a PDF. Simple enough. The problem that I am experiencing is that my code only selects part of `Sheet4`, so in my PDF part of the sheet is missing.

`Sheet4` contains data in range `A1:W80`. However, when running the code below only the range `A1:W75` is selected for printing. I have confirmed my `PrintArea` contains the entire page. Everything even looks great when printing.

I have searched endlessly for a solution, with no success. Could this be a page-layout setting issue? How can I ensure I am selecting the entire sheet, instead of only part of it, when exporting to PDF?

Here is my code:

```
Sub SaveReportPDF()

    Dim filepath As String

    filepath = "ABC"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=filepath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Select` does not make `Selection` the entire sheet - it just selects the 4 sheets and makes the `Selection` on each sheet the same as what it is on Sheet1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As good practise, you can set your used range of each sheet as the print area, and fit it to the page, using the following sub:

```
Sub ScaleForPrinting()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    ' Stop PrintCommunication for speed
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    ' Cycle through each sheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"))
        ' Set print area to used range of sheet
        sh.PageSetup.PrintArea = sh.UsedRange
        ' Remove zoom, scale sheet to fit 1 page
        With sh.PageSetup
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = True
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
    Next sh
    ' Enable PrintCommunication to apply settings
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Then you will want to use the `ActiveSheet` object after selecting, rather than the `Selection` object. This is perhaps counter-intuitive, but you want to print the *sheets* not what you've selected *in the sheets*.

So:

```
ScaleForPrinting
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=filepath, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
' Deselect sheets to avoid nasty multiple sheet accidental editing!
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```